# Non localized error messages in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, debugging

I've got a Polish version of Windows installed and therefore I get exception messages in Polish. Is there a way to make asp.net display error messages in English? Other than installing English version of Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to the system.web section of your web.config file:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" />
```

This should work unless:

- you have changed the uiCulture explicitly elsewhere (e.g. multilingual web apps may change the uiCulture for each request)
- the error you are getting occurs before the web.config file is processed.